# Adding a GET parameter to URL causes 404 error

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to install the [syntaxhighlightter evolved](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/) plugin to my wordpress blog. I've uploaded and activated the plugin, but it did not work. I've looked into the page source code and found out that the plugin style is loaded from the following URL:

http://devermind.com/wp-content/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/syntaxhighlighter/styles/shCore.css?ver=2.0.320

This causes a 404 error (page not found). The strange thing though is that when I remove the GET parameters, the CSS loads ok:

http://devermind.com/wp-content/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/syntaxhighlighter/styles/shCore.css

What could be causing this problem and how can I fix this? Unfortunately I don't know how to make wordpress drop the GET parameters when loading the stylesheet.

**EDIT:** As I just found out, this happens only in Firefox (3.0.11). IE loads both URLs above just fine. Not that this would be of any help though, so any suggestions would be appreciated.

**SECOND EDIT:** I tried this on my laptop and it works fine with Firefox 3.08. So this really seems to be a browser problem after all.

Comment: http://devermind.com/wp-content/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/syntaxhighlighter/styles/shCore.css?ver=2.0.320 gives me 200 O...

Comment: You're right - It works fine, but not in Firefox

Comment: FWIW, it works fine with Firefox here.

Comment: Are you using the same Firefox version (3.0.11)? Also, Did you really use the faulty link (the first one above, not the second)?

Comment: Works with Safari 4, confirmed with curl as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works with my Firefox version 3.0.11 and the link with the ver=2.0.320 parameter.

Did you check with your Firefox and disabling all extensions? Just create a new profile, that should disable them all. Check out the [Mozilla knowledge base](http://support.mozilla.com/kb/Managing+Profiles) on how to create a new profile.

Comment: Bullseye! It's working fine when using another Firefox profile. Strangely enough, just launching it in safe mode does not help. Now I'll just have to troubleshoot my regular profile.

Comment: Check your server logs to see what the requested URL is.  This may give you a hint at what's going on in the browser.  I suspect something is encoding the URL and converting "?" to "%3f".

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone is still interested in this, in my case the problem was the HTTP proxy Fiddler, which seems to manipulate such URLs out of the box.

Turning off Fiddler capture solves the problem.